# nodejs can't recieve req from flutter

Tags: mysql, node.js, flutter, express, http

```
can't find solution from my code where i tried to send datas from flutter to express.js
```

this my code in flutter

```
try{
    var regbody={
      "username":username,
      "fullname":fullname,
      "password":password,
      "image":image,
    };
    print(regbody);
    var response=await http.post(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.10:5000/datauser"),headers: {
      // 'Accept':'application/json',
      'Content-Type':'aplication/json',

    },
        body: json.encode(regbody)
    );
```

this my code in express.js controller

```
 if(req.files===null) return res.status(400).json({msg:"no file registered"});
    
    const username=req.body.username;
    const fullname=req.body.fullname;
    const password=req.body.password;
    const img=req.body.image;

    async(error)=>{
        if(error) return res.status(500).json({msg:error.message});
        try {
            await dataUser.create({username:username,fullname:fullname,password:password,image:img,url:"hhh"});
            res.status(201).json({msg:"Registration Successfully!"});
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
```

from above code the values of req are null and when i tried with console.log the req it return undefines

i'm expecting datas that i post in flutter could recieved by express.js so ican store those datas to database,,,anybody please help me to find what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What are the exact errors that you get on express side? Did you try commenting out the first line which returns 400 ? just to make sure you see the request being received? What else have you tried in order to solve your issue? I do not see any debugging being used?

Comment: Executing (default): INSERT INTO `datauser` (`id`,`url`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?);  this is a response when i tried in emulator

and this is a response when i tried in postman
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `datauser` (`id`,`username`,`fullname`,`password`,`image`,`url`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);

Comment: i'm a new in flutter so i dont anything else what should i do

Comment: I think I gave you a number of hints... try to confirm that flutter is indeed sending a HTTP request with the posted data, then also try to confirm via debugging if express is receiving ANY requests... also read again my first comment... once you can confirm you are receiving the data, then you get to myql and import what you need to...

Comment: Did you try commenting out the first line which returns 400  // idid -
just to make sure you see the request being received //well this is my problem

Comment: yes, you seem to not be seding in your request any FILES, which triggers this check, and directly blocks anything further, so you might want to change that logic to also work hen there's no FILES sent..

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable your first line, as you seem to not be sending in your request any FILES, which triggers this check, and directly blocks anything further, so you might want to change that logic to also work hen there's no FILES sent..

```
 if(req.files===null) return res.status(400).json({msg:"no file registered"});
```

Comment: i tried and it still can't recieve data from flutter